Не прорисовываются автоматически картики после ajax-запроса и рендеринга страницы
Не прорисовываются картинки (только картинки) после выполнения ajax-запроса и рендеринга фрагмента страницы в таргетированном div. С адресами все в порядке. Картинка прорисовывается, как только системе приходится обновить весь экран (допустим - потянуть скроллом вверх или вниз). Сам ajax запрос может возвращать фильтрованных список в виде products:
...
{% for product in products %}
        ...
        <div class="no-margin col-xs-12 col-sm-4 image-holder">
            <div class="image">
                <img alt="" src="{% static 'assets/images/blank.gif' %}" data-echo="{{ product.images.first.image.url }}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
{% endfor %}

Или даже в элементе карусели картинок при прокручивании первые четыре показываются, потому как "географически" попадают в область экрана монитора, а пятая уже лежит за его пределами, и когда карусель до нее доходит, получаю белое поле. Картинка подгружается только после малейшего движения экрана:
<div id="owl-single-product" class="owl-carousel">
    {% for image in product.images.all %}
        <div class="single-product-gallery-item" id="slide{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <a data-rel="prettyphoto" href="{{ image.image.url }}">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="{% static 'assets/images/blank.gif' %}" data-echo="{{ image.image.url }}" height="325" width="433"/>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.single-product-gallery-item -->
    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- /.single-product-slider -->

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону думать. Всю логику расписал, как надо, фильтрация работает, эту проблему оставил на потом. Вот сейчас вернулся и не нахожу, с какой стороны подойти. Заранее спасибо
